# What should I modify in this recursion-using deep level flatten code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to enable deep level flatten use recursion with reduce and concat.
But when I compile it, the Typeerror like bellow is occured.

TypeError: arr.reduce is not a function

I guess the problem has something to do with type of argument what flattenDeep received.

Can you give me a hint?

```js
function joinArrayOfArrays(arr) {
  var output=[];
  flattenDeep(arr);
  return arr;

}
function flattenDeep(arr2){
  return arr2.reduce((acc,val)=> Array.isArray(arr2) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val));
}
```

Comment: Don't check `Array.isArray(arr2)`, check `Array.isArray(val)`. Also provide an initial value

Comment: Also try clicking [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57320819/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor, then you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: you need to return the result of flattening as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check each time whether the current value is an array, so use `val` not `arr2`. And give an empty array as a starting value for `reduce`.

```
return arr2.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was confused about using method reduce. Now I get it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

your error is here `Array.isArray(arr2) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : ...` you check wether `arr2` is an array, but then you (try to) flatten `val`. You should check wether `isArray(val)` instead.

Besides that, `Array#concat()` would not be my choice. Because, in this code, it creates an intermediate array for every iteration. Then copies all entries over, adds the new one(s) and throws the old array away; what a waste. I'd create a single output Array and push all the items into that.

```
// the recursive part; the reducer
function _flatten(acc, arg) {
  return Array.isArray(arg) ? 
    arg.reduce(_flatten, acc) : 
    (acc.push(arg), acc);
}

function flatten(arg) {
  return _flatten([], arg);
}
```

This construct `(acc.push(arg), acc)` does `Array#push()` and returns the array instead of the new length.